# Array as argument to function

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

Here in f() I accept array to be of maximum size 4 but it still runs fine when I pass an array of size greater than 4(here 10), I know arrays in c++ are passed as pointers by default but than when is this method of passing array useful?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int a[4]){
    for(int i  = 0;i < 3;i++){
        a[i] += 10;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[10];
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        a[i] = i;
    f(a);
    for(int i =0 ;i < 10;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

output: 10 11 12 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead

Comment: That is the curse of C arrays. You cannot put them in function parameters or return them. You have to find some workaround of using a pointer or reference to the array or stuffing the array in a struct (which is what `std::array` is).

Comment: I just wanted to know why is this method of accepting array in c++ used

Comment: "why is this method of accepting array in c++ used" for compatibility with C

Comment: I heard the reason is that in early C, wanting to pass an array by value was unthinkable and most definitely a performance bug. So they decided to silently fix your performance bug by turning the array into a pointer.

Comment: Okay got you, this means this method is not of any importance in c++@nwp

Comment: I suggest you avoid C arrays as much as you can. Usually, but not always, `std::array` is straight-up better.

Comment: @nwp The "arrays are pointers" confusion dates back to BCPL (from which C derives via B).  At that point arrays *were* pointers.  Declaring a variable as an array allocated the specified number of words somewhere (I can remember if it was heap or stack), and initialized the variable with their address.  So "can't pass arrays by value" is very old indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make `f()` more restrictive as shown by @songyuanyao or consider using a C++ `std::array` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// make an alias for the array you'd like to accept
using myarray_t = std::array<int, 4>;

// accept the array by reference
void f(myarray_t& a) {
    // use a range based for loop to access elements by reference
    for(int& a_i : a) a_i += 10;
}

int main() {
    // declare your array
    myarray_t a;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) a[i] = static_cast<int>(i);
    f(a);
    // and you can use a range based for loop to extract by value too 
    for(int a__i : a)
        std::cout << a_i << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I know arrays in c++ are passed as pointers by default

Correct.

This:

```
void foo(int a[4])
```

is literally rewritten to this:

```
void foo(int* a)
```

… and then when you call the function your array's name decays to the pointer, matching the rewritten/"real" argument type.

So you're not really passing an array at all.

> When is this method of passing array useful?

Never.

This is a shameful oddity inherited from C. One might argue that the `[4]` is a useful hint to the developer that the pointed-to array "should" have four elements, but modern wisdom is that this is just unnecessarily and dangerously misleading.

Better alternatives include:

- Pointer/size pair (two arguments): this is not less dangerous *per se*, but at least it does not lie about the type and lull you into a false sense of security!
- Array by reference: lovely jubbly, but less flexible
- `std::array<int, 4>` (by reference): as above, but neater

Comment: Or switch to `std::vector` instead of an array - this is almost always my first suggestion.

Comment: @MartinBonner Probably overkill for four `int`s but worth considering _if_ you need the resizable storage (if not, there's really no reason to prefer `vector` over `array`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to impose restrictions on the size of the array passed in, you can change to pass-by-reference.

```
void f(int (&a)[4]){
    for(int i  = 0;i < 3;i++){
        a[i] += 10;
    }
}
```

`void f(int a[4])` is same as `void f(int* a)`; that means you can pass the array with any size which will decay to pointer (i.e. `int*`) when being passed.